# A circle on the plane.

Tags: geometry

I have this problem:

Let $C$ be a circle in the $xy$-plane with center on the $y$-axis and passing through $A=(0,a)$ and $B=(0,b)$ with $0<a<b$. Let $P$ be any other point on the circle, let $Q$ be the intersection of the line through $P$ and $A$ with the $x$-axis and let $O=(0,0)$. Prove that $\angle BQP = \angle BOP$.

I don't know how to attack it. I really appreciate any clever suggestions.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: BPOQ is concyclic, hence the angles are equal.

Proof: observe that angles BPQ and BOQ are right.

Comment: I don't get it. How do you get that $BPOQ$ is concyclic using that $BPQ$ and $BOQ$ are right?

Comment: Angles in the same segment are equal. The converse is true, that if two angles are equal then they are in the same segment and hence the points are concyclic

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The two right triangles shaded above are similar. Therefore we have $$\frac{GD}{ED}=\frac{FD}{DB}$$ Also the interior angles are equal because they are alternate. Therefore the two (un-shaded) triangles are similar and the angles must be equal (by SAS similarity).